# Interface TFT display with STM32 parallel connection

Tags: arduino, stm32, stm32cubemx, parallel-port

I am searching for an explanation for the coding idiom for changing TFT
display resolution that is used in the PORT from [mcufriend’s Arduino code](https://controllerstech.com/interface-tft-display-with-stm32/%20https://github.com/prenticedavid/MCUFRIEND_kbv).

`init_table16(R61509V_regValues, sizeof(R61509V_regValues));`

1. `p16 = (int16_t *) & _height;`
2. `*p16 = 400;`

Statements 1 and 2 are to adjust the vertical resolution. I do understand this.

1. `p16 int16_t* 0x2000000c<_height>`
   To allocate memory for _height in STM32F103 SRAM (64 KB aliased by bit-banding)
2. To assign value (400) to the location.

Now the magic has happened and the resolution of the ST7793 has been adjusted over the parallel interface.

Comment: the URL is broken

Comment: what is your specific question? ... `I am searching for...` is not a question

Comment: whether you are asking for a place where the information can be found or you are asking for an explanation, your post is about programming and belongs at https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: Your line #1 does not allocate any memory to anything. It assigns the value of the address of the `_height` variable to the pointer variable `p16`. Without more context it's not clear to me why both line couldn't have been simple combined into `_height = 400;`.

Comment: The _height variable does not directly involve to sending a command over 8080 parallel port to the ST7793 chip. How does variable _height affect the resolution? This is a question.

Comment: init_table16(R61509V_regValues, sizeof(R61509V_regValues));

Comment: init_table16(R61509V_regValues, sizeof(R61509V_regValues)); sends commands to ST7793 chip. Then the resolution is adjusted via variable _height in a mystic way. The question is not about coding but about the STM32 coding idiom.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `p16 = (int16_t *) & _height;` is giving access to bit-banding memory. `*p16 = 400;` is setting individual bits to peripheral registers mapping to a bit-banding region of M3 memory. This is how a miracle is created. I will spend the rest of my life learning the black magic of computing and sharing my experience. Thank you for your support.